# Angularjs compile dynamic html to isolated scope on directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Im trying to build a simple directive that uses jquery ui pop-over, for confirmation on simple actions (like, are you sure you want to .....).

My directive looks like this:

```
(function () {

    var __directive = function ($compile, appSettings) {

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                callback: '&',
                options: '=?'
            },            
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs, component) {
                var html = '<div id="POPOVER"><div class="modal-header">Confirmación</div><div class="modal-body">' +                
                            scope.options.message + scope +
                            '</div><div class="modal-footer"><div class="form-inline"><button type="button" id="btnYes" ng-click="yes()" class="btn btn-primary">'
                            + appSettings.confirmar + '</button>' +
                            '<span style="margin: 0 10px;">' + appSettings.or + '</span>' +
                            '<a class="under" id="btnNo" >' + appSettings.cancelar + '</a></div></div></div>';

                scope.yes = function () {
                    console.log('it worked'); // THIS IS NOT HAPPENING AT ALL
                    scope.callback();
                };

                var el = angular.element(html);
                var compiled = $compile(el)(scope);

                var __options = {
                    html: true,
                    placement: attrs.popOverPlacement,
                    content: function () {
                        return compiled;
                    }
                };                

                $(elem).popover(__options);   // Jquery                 

            }
        }
    }

    __directive.$inject = ['$compile', 'appSettings'];
    angular.module('agenciaVirtualApp').directive('ngPopover', __directive);

}())
```

And its used like:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-popover callback="DeleteAction()" pop-over-placement='top' options="SomeOptions">Eliminar</button>
```

My problem is that ng-click="yes()" is not triggering at all.! I want this to work this way. I tryed using a workaround with Jquery, with something like:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnYes', function(){ scope.callback(); }) // THIS WORKS, BUT TRIGGERS TWICE
```

This workaround works, but for some reason, callback is called twice (lame...)

So, I want it to work the angular way, what I'm doing wrong.? any ideas?

Comment: Tried your code in Plunker and both scope.yes and scope.callback was executed on click.

Comment: Can you post the plunker code you tried ? pls

Comment: Sorry, thought I did: http://plnkr.co/edit/8CIXT1AVjo9iArfdhS3E?p=preview

Comment: Well, just like you said, it works on plunker. So I started adding and removing things from my code. Turns out I have a call to a CDN form Bootstrap on http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js and for some reason , If I replace that call for the one you have on //netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js IT WORKS..... (Idk why, but it does). Anyways, thanks for the help. If you post your reply as a "Reply" and not a comment, Ill mark it as "THE ANSWER", jeje

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the urls you are referencing //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js and //netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js you should see the difference. The cdnjs url is referencing version 2.1.0 of bootstrap and the netdna url is referencing version 3.1.1. If you would like to use cdnjs update the link to the same version http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js or try out the latest stable version at the time of this post http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js